# What does 'Background' annotation in appium .feature file mean?

Tags: cucumber, appium

I am new to Appium and I don't know what does `Background:` do in `.feature` file in Appium. Can any one please explain it to me?

As per my understanding, the test steps which are placed under `Background:` are executed every time after the end of one scenario.

Comment: Just to emphasize the fact that it has nothing to do with Appium as it's a Cucumber feature.

Comment: The steps in the `Background` block will be executed before each scenario current `*.feature` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A background section in a feature file allows you to specify a set of steps that
are common to every scenario in the file. So instead of having to repeat those steps over and over for each scenario, you can move them up into a Background
element.

The advantages to doing this are:

- If you ever need to change those steps, you have to change them in only
  one place.
- The importance of those steps fades into the background so that when
  you’re reading each individual scenario, you can focus on what is unique
  and important about that scenario.

For example consider the following 2 scenarios:

```
Scenario: Change PIN successfully
  Given I have been issued a new card
  And I insert the card, entering the correct PIN
  When I choose "Change PIN" from the menu
  And I change the PIN to 9876
  Then the system should remember my PIN is now 9876

Scenario: Try to change PIN to the same as before
  Given I have been issued a new card
  And I insert the card, entering the correct PIN
  When I choose "Change PIN" from the menu
  And I try to change the PIN to the original PIN number
  Then I should see a warning message
  And the system should not have changed my PIN
```

From the above 2 scenarios you can see that the first few steps repeat themselves in each scenario. So what we could do is to move them to background and then they will be executed in the beginning of each scenario automatically.

```
Background:
  Given I have been issued a new card
  And I insert the card, entering the correct PIN
  And I choose "Change PIN" from the menu

Scenario: Change PIN successfully
  When I change the PIN to 9876
  Then the system should remember my PIN is now 9876

Scenario: Try to change PIN to the same as before
  When I try to change the PIN to the original PIN number
  Then I should see a warning message
  And the system should not have changed my PIN
```

Comment: Thanks a lott @Eugene S